# get trip period in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a GPS app that saves data to the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Tracking]
(
    [id]          [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IMEI]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TrackTime]   [datetime] NULL,
    [Longitude]   [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Lattitude]   [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [speed]       [float] NULL,
    [CarID]       [int] NULL,
    [Country]     [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [City]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Area]        [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Street]      [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FullAddress] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Distance]    [float] NULL
    -- ...
)
```

I want to make a trip query pulling back start time & speed, and end time & speed.

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT id
, IMEI
, TrackTime as StartTime
, speed as StartSpeed
, CarID
, FullAddress
, (
    SELECT TOP (1) TrackTime AS Expr1
    FROM T_Tracking AS E2
    WHERE (CarID = E1.CarID) 
    AND (id > E1.id) 
    AND (speed <5)
    ORDER BY id desc
) AS StopTime 
, (
    SELECT TOP (1) speed AS Expr1
    FROM T_Tracking AS E2
    WHERE (CarID = E1.CarID) 
    AND (id > E1.id) 
    AND (speed <5)      
    ORDER BY id desc
) AS EndSpeed 
FROM T_Tracking AS E1 
WHERE (speed > 5) 
order by id desc
```

It works fine, but to decide that it is the end if the trip the car should be stopping for 15 minutes (i.e. as the car might stop in traffic for a minute or 2, so we don't want that to count as the end of the trip).
How can I add this logic?

Additionally, I need to sum the distance field to get the trip total distance.

Sample Table Data:

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

Notes:

1. the GPS get save a record every 30 sec
2. the car may be stopping in traffic so to decide it is the end of the trip it must be stopping for 15 min
3. stop not always `speed=0` it will be `speed<5` (Device accuracy / tolerance)
4. distance is the distance between the current point and the previous (distance in the 30 sec)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Post updated for better explination

Comment: Thanks for the edit Waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

This is demo how you can get stops. For simplicity I used all INT to represent time and speed, the query can be easily adapted for DATETIME data type. The stop is logged if it's duration > 4.

```
SELECT CarID, stopped, grp 
   , min(TrackTime) stopStartTime
   , max(TrackTime) + 1 - min(TrackTime) stopDuration
FROM (
    SELECT id, TrackTime, CarID, stopped
      , row_number() over (partition by CarID order by TrackTime) - row_number() over (partition by CarID, stopped order by TrackTime)  grp
    FROM (
        SELECT id, TrackTime, CarID, CASE WHEN speed > 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END stopped
        FROM (
            -- Demo data
            VALUES 
             (0,0,10, 2)
            ,(1,1,10, 8)
            ,(2,2,10, 8)
            ,(3,3,10, 4)
            ,(4,4,10, 4)
            ,(5,5,10, 4)
            ,(6,6,10, 4)
            ,(7,7,10, 4)
            ,(8,8,10, 4)
            ,(9,9,10, 8)
        ) T_Tracking (id, TrackTime, CarID, speed)
    ) g
 ) t
 GROUP BY CarID, stopped, grp
 HAVING max(TrackTime) + 1 - min(TrackTime) > 4
 ORDER BY min(TrackTime)
```

Comment: max(TrackTime) + 1 - min(TrackTime) > 4 the 4 here mean stopping for 4 minutes ??  what grp ???

Comment: Yes, 4 units (minutes, hours,...) it' s just INT value.

Comment: thank you for the query but its missing some things First the start speen and end speed i could't put the speed in the query since it need to be grouped by which will be wrong and the same for start and end address second how to get sum of distance

Comment: To get the rest of the data you need to compare the stops result above to the source data and get all the info concerning speeds etc, related to the stop. Please provide  your data in SQL consumable format if more assistance needed.

Comment: i did provide image of the data how to send data sample

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
select JourneyBounds.id
, JourneyBounds.IMEI
, JourneyBounds.TrackTime as StartTime
, JourneyBounds.speed as StartSpeed
, JourneyBounds.CarID
, JourneyBounds.FullAddress
, max(journey.TrackTime) StopTime
, max(case when journey.id = JourneyBounds.EndOfJourneyId then journey.speed else null end) EndSpeed
, JourneyBounds.Distance + sum(journey.Distance) TotalDistance 
from (
    select *
    , (
        select min(id) 
        from T_Tracking EndOfJourney
        where EndOfJourney.Id > StartOfJourney.Id
        and EndOfJourney.CarId = StartOfJourney.CarId
        and EndOfJourney.speed < 5
        --edit; car must have been stopped for 15 mins; so we need to check that the records after this stop confirm that (i.e. that the car does not move in that time)
        and not exists (
            select top 1 1
            from T_Tracking WaitFifteenMins
            where WaitFifteenMins.Id > EndOfJourney.Id
            and WaitFifteenMins.TrackTime <= DateAdd(minute, 15, EndOfJourney.TrackTime)
            and WaitFifteenMins.speed >= 5
        ) 
        --end of edit
    ) EndOfJourneyId 
    from T_Tracking StartOfJourney
    where StartOfJourney.speed < 5
) JourneyBounds
inner join T_Tracking journey
on journey.CarId = JourneyBounds.CarId 
and journey.id > JourneyBounds.Id 
and journey.id <= JourneyBounds.EndOfJourneyId
group by JourneyBounds.id
, JourneyBounds.IMEI
, JourneyBounds.TrackTime 
, JourneyBounds.speed
, JourneyBounds.CarID
, JourneyBounds.FullAddress
, JourneyBounds.Distance 
having count(1) > 1
```

The `JourneyBounds` subquery gets all records with `speed < 5` (i.e. the start records for any potential journeys).  Additionally it pulls back the `id` of the first stop after that start (i.e. the first record with a greater id which has a speed of less than 5).

It then does an inner join pulling back all records for the same car which come after the start time, up to & including the end record for this journey.  We then calculate the distance by summing all distances of the records on this journey.

The `having count(1) > 1` on the end just says if the car's start record is immediately followed by a stop, we can assume it's not moved / there was no journey.  Presumably we don't want those non-journeys in our results.

Comment: error in StartOfJourney is not found ??
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The multi-part identifier "StartOfJourney.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The multi-part identifier "StartOfJourney.EndOfJourneyId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "StartOfJourney.EndOfJourneyId" could not be bound.

Comment: Apologies; used `StartOfJourney` instead of `JourneyBounds` in the outer SQL.  Corrected.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
The multi-part identifier "StartOfJourney.Id" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid column name 'EndOfJourneyId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'EndOfJourneyId'.

Comment: Sorry; think I've pokemonned it now.

Comment: 'minutes' is not a recognized dateadd option. 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid column name 'EndOfJourneyId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'EndOfJourneyId'.
Using SqlServer 2014

Comment: still the invalid column error 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Invalid column name 'EndOfJourneyId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'EndOfJourneyId'.
should it be EndOfJourney

Comment: Last fix done: `EndOfJourneyId` had been in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi the query still running 20Minutes and still no result table row count 953137 i didn't know if it is correct

Comment: Looks like relying on `id` isn't a good idea because GPS packets may arrive  to the DB not strictly in sequence of TrackTime.

Comment: What indexes do you have?  Is `Id` your clustered index?

Comment: CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Tracking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: still no result after 90 minutes executing

Comment: No Solution Yet Any Help ??